# RobotFramework / Selenium Firefox: this-event not working?

Tags: selenium, firefox, robotframework, geckodriver, webdriverwait

I encountered a problem automating a test-procedure on my website. I there have a list of items and - to add a new one - a modal openes. Everything's fine til then - the RobotFramework fills out the checkboxes and inputs with text, but when it comes to the "Save"-button, Chrome and Firefox response differently.

Chrome does everything correct, closing the modal and saving the new item. Firefox on the other hand seems to click the button too, but nothing happens. The code "behind" the button is as follows:

```
<button id="submitSomething" type="submit" name="someName"
        value="Save" onclick="window.wishlist.editPreSubmit(this, event)">Save</button>
```

- Python 2.7.x (latest) 32 bit
- wxPython 2.8 32 bit
- geckodriver latest 64 bit
- chromedriver 2.45

I tried somehing like:

```
Execute Javascript    document.querySelector("#submitNew").click()
```

instead of

```
Click Button    id=submitSomething
```

but without a change on Firefox sadly. Every tiny help would be greatly appreciated :)

**Edit:**
If I use

```
document.querySelector("#submitNew").click()
```

in the console of the browser which was opened from robotframework, it does not work either (firefox) and I get a warning:

> form posted in windows-1252-codec, should be changed to utf-8

Br

Comment: What happens if you execute the Javascript manually from Firefox console?

Comment: Also, did you try Click Element instead of Click Button?

Comment: I tried Click Element as well as Button and Link, but no chance. If I execute "document.querySelector("#submitNew").click()" in console in Firefox, it works - like if I manually click the button, that also works.
If I use the Firefox-Extension for Selenium or RIDE, it does not work sadly.

Comment: Interesting. Not saying that this is a solution - but I would try performing the same action in "clean" Firefox session, e.g. on Browserstack as it might be an issue with your product rather than Robot/Selenum (e.g. encoding - app works correctly when you're using your browser as it's got a different language locale set than the one used with webdriver)

Comment: I tried that out and it does not work eighter, same warning message as above - ofc if I use the console-approach only. Clicking the button manually does the trik even in the "clean" browserstack-firefox

Comment: Have you tried slowing down Selenium with some additional Sleep steps?

Answer (score -1):

To click the desired element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `Wait Until Element Is Visible`:

  ```
  Wait Until Element Is Visible    xpath=//button[@id='submitSomething' and @value='Save'][contains(., 'Save')]    20  seconds
  Set Focus To Element    xpath=//button[@id='submitSomething' and @value='Save'][contains(., 'Save')]
  # invoke click
  ```
- `Wait Until Element Is Enabled`:

  ```
  Wait Until Element Is Enabled    xpath=//button[@id='submitSomething' and @value='Save'][contains(., 'Save')]    20  seconds
  Set Focus To Element    xpath=//button[@id='submitSomething' and @value='Save'][contains(., 'Save')]
  # invoke click
  ```